# How can I get the name of the calling function in C#?

Tags: c#

I need to get the name of the calling function in C#. I read about stackframe method but everywhere its said its not reliable and hurts the performance.

But I need it for production use. I am writing a custom tracer which will be logging the name of the method from which trace was called as well.

Could someone please help with a efficient method to get the calling function name? I am using Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: Could you please specify if it's for asp.net or winforms so that you can get more help? :)

Comment: I'm not sure if anything using that sort of granular reflection could be called "efficient", per se.

Comment: Would something like [PostSharp](http://www.sharpcrafters.com/) help you?

Comment: The stacktrace has been pretty reliable for me, and if it's what you need to do then you just need to suck up the performance implications of reflection.

Comment: I can manually add function Name to every trace line which is time consuming process but if stackframe hits the performance too much I would have to go that route. Just wanted to know if there is any other efficient way.

Comment: It's not what you want, but for private calls within your method hierarchy, you could manage it yourself by giving every method an additional stack argument, and then only grab from the stackframe upon entering your code, thus limiting your exposure to the performance/correctness problems you mention.

Why do you need this, though?  For production code, this feels a little like a code-smell to me.

Comment: It will be used for debugging only in case of issues.

Comment: @HanletEscaño This is for backend service.

Answer (score 12):

upgrade to c# 5 and use `CallerMemberName`

```
public void Method([CallerMemberName] string caller="")
{
}
```

**EDIT**

Other nice things with c# 5

```
public void Method([CallerMemberName] string name="",
                   [CallerLineNumber] int line=-1,
                   [CallerFilePath] string path="")
{
}
```

Comment: Wow, I wasn't aware that C# 5 exists. Is this the Jon Skeet edition, finally?

Comment: @UweKeim haven't you heard VS2012?

Comment: :( Its not my decision to take.

Comment: @LB saw these on stackoverflow somewhere but its only for .NET4.5 and above :(

Comment: @shobhit Yes, version numbering is weird, c#5 comes with .Net 4.5

Comment: Declare the types yourself and enjoy this feature with .NET 3.5 and above as long as you compile with the vs2012 compiler: see my answer below.

Answer (score 9):

You can do something like:

```
 var stackTrace = new StackTrace();
 var name = stackTrace.GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name;
```

and it work with any version of the framework/language.

Comment: also may work differently based on what configuration you build in, and what optimizations are made... and if anything is inlined... it was quite a pain to use.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the C# 4.5 Attributes mentioned in L.B's answer with .NET 3.5 or above by simply declaring them (you need to compile using vs2012 or higher, else **you won't get any error, but the parameter value will stay null!**):

```
namespace System.Runtime.CompilerServices
{
  [AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Parameter, Inherited = false)]
  public sealed class CallerMemberNameAttribute : Attribute
  {
  }

  [AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Parameter, Inherited = false)]
  public sealed class CallerFilePathAttribute : Attribute
  {
  }

  [AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Parameter, Inherited = false)]
  public sealed class CallerLineNumberAttribute : Attribute
  {
  }
}
```

Comment: Excellent!! This works like a charm. It saves our current project from a lot of trouble upgrading all of our build services. Thanks!

Comment: @Jakob: But keep in mind: the build agents must use vs2012 or else the method argument will always be null, making you a lot of (performance) trouble when used in INotifyPropertyChanged-Implementations for example...

Comment: Yes, I noticed this the hard way ... :) One of our build servers could not be upgraded yet so we were stuck. What I do now is checking for incoming file and member information. If it is entered by caller attributes I am happy, but if not I have a fallback to old fashion StackTrace lookup. This way I can use the correct method signatures already and have the expected information. When our server is upgraded in a month or two I will automatically get the performance boost.