# Getting Class name that instantiated another class

Tags: c#, .net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I get the name of the calling function in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12098267/how-can-i-get-the-name-of-the-calling-function-in-c)

I am looking for some insight into how to best get some info.

This app is C#.net

We have a series of classes that are all derived off an abstract base class. These series of classes are instantiated in other methods in a set of business rule classes.

I'm adding some logging and would like to be able to log which class instantiated the class. The most appropriate place for this is in the abstract base class.

I know how to get the stackTrace and inspect the frames, but am not quite sure what the right way to definitively identify who created the class. There are a lot of "builder" and other levels of abstraction between the base class and the one creating the class derived from the base class.

Any thoughts or insights are appreciated.

Comment: OP wants to get the class name. The linked "duplicate" wants to get the function name.

Comment: @Greg Aren't calling methods in .Net always associated with Class? I'd assume so, therefore getting the class of a method is another reflection step away...

Comment: you'd have to walk the stack trace and using knowledge of the builders and abstractions, find the first place outside that.  only you know that information.  but the information you want is *somewhere* in the stack trace.

Comment: From the possible duplicate `new StackTrace().GetFrame(1).GetMethod().DeclaringType` will return the Type of the calling method's class.

Comment: @Mike: Yes, but if the requested caller is an unknown number of frames up, that could become tricky... OP: Is there a single point of entry when you instansiate? Could you add some illustrative code?

Comment: Could use dependency injection.  Windsor at least lets you inspect the component resolution process.

Comment: You want something very strange. Could you say what exactly do you want and why do you want this?