# Get method name of a delegate passed as a parameter (Compact Framework)

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda, delegates, compact-framework

I have a function that takes a Func as a parameter, invokes it, and outputs some results. For logging purposes, it would be nice to be able to be able to access the name of the function that is actually being called when the lambda expression executes. Is there a way to do this in compact framework?

```
    Private Function tryWithLogging(ByVal moveFunc As Func(Of Boolean)) As Boolean
        Try
            moveFunc.Invoke()
            Dim nameOfMethod as String = '??????
             Console.WriteLine("Invoked " & nameOfMethod)
        Catch ex As Exception
        End Try
    End Function
```

Example usage:

```
tryWithLogging(Function() myFunction([arbitrary params]) 
'desired output: "Invoked myFunction"
```

Here's what I have attempted to retrieve the name:

```
moveFunc.Method.Name 'returns whatever the compiler decided to name the lambda

New StackTrace().GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name 'works, but is not available on CF
```

I have also tried passing an `Expression(Of Func(Of Boolean))` instead and getting the name from that, but `System.Linq.Expressions` is also not available on CF.

Is there any way to retrieve the name of a function being invoked by a lambda within the shackles of compact framework 3.5?

Comment: Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12098267/how-can-i-get-the-name-of-the-calling-function-in-c?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @L.B perhaps I am misunderstanding your link, but I don't think `CallerMemberName` will help me. I want the name of the method _being_ invoked in the lambda, not the name of the function doing the invoking.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately no, there's no way to get it (you can't get the caller name either, short of throwing an exception and manually parsing the stack trace).  Bear in mind the CF you're using is a full decade old.  Even then it didn't have all of the niceties of the full framework.